# ORACLE DB user_constraints without tables

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle schema with no tables (I dropped them).  When I look at the `user_constraints` table, however

```
    SELECT * FROM user_constraints;
```

I see a number of rows. How is it possible to delete these constraints?

```
    DELETE FROM user_constraints WHERE owner='owner';
```

did not work, it gave me an "insufficient privileges" error.

```
    SELECT owner, constraint_name, constraint_type, table_name, r_owner, r_constraint_name  FROM user_constraints;

    OWNER                          CONSTRAINT_NAME                CONSTRAINT_TYPE TABLE_NAME                     R_OWNER                        R_CONSTRAINT_NAME            
    ORA_AI_1_9                     BIN$z2XwnFUHEHrgQ4sGOR4Qeg==$0 P               BIN$z2XwnFUJEHrgQ4sGOR4Qeg==$0                                                               

    ORA_AI_1_9                     BIN$z1NhC6g4oErgQ4sGOR6gSg==$0 P               BIN$z1NhC6g6oErgQ4sGOR6gSg==$0                                                               

    ORA_AI_1_9                     BIN$z1anK5OEEHrgQ4sGOR4Qeg==$0 P               BIN$z1anK5OGEHrgQ4sGOR4Qeg==$0                                                               

    ORA_AI_1_9                     BIN$z1NhC6hhoErgQ4sGOR6gSg==$0 P               BIN$z1NhC6hjoErgQ4sGOR6gSg==$0
```

Comment: When you say that you deleted them, do you really mean that you dropped the tables?  Or did you merely delete the data?  Are there rows in `user_tables`?

Comment: i dropped the tables.  user_tables is empty

Comment: your output shows recyclebin..see answer for details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so are you on 10/11g and have the recylebin perhaps?

```
SQL> select count(*) from user_tables;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL> select count(*) from user_constraints;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL> create table foo(id number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET recyclebin = ON;

Session altered.

SQL> select count(*) from user_tables;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SQL> select count(*) from user_constraints;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SQL> drop table foo;

Table dropped.

SQL> select count(*) from user_constraints;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SQL> select count(*) from user_tables;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL>
```

you can purge the reclebin to fix this.

```
SQL> purge recyclebin;

Recyclebin purged.

SQL> select count(*) from user_constraints;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

Answer (score 1):

you can give statement like `DROP TABLE [schema.]table_name [CASCADE CONSTRAINTS]`

Comment: i droped the latest tables like this. before I used the gui of SQL DEVELOPER. right now I have no tables.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should never do DML directly against a data dictionary table like `user_constraints`.

Second, do you own constraints that are created on tables owned by other users?  What does

```
SELECT owner, constraint_name, constraint_type, table_name, r_owner, r_constraint_name
  FROM user_constraints
```

return?

Comment: A table with ~300 rows. im the only user. its an account from our school for every student.

Comment: @user1069968 - So there are no other schemas in this database?  That seems highly unlikely in a school setting-- it would be very, very unusual to give every student a separate database instance.  Can you edit your question to post the actual results of this query (feel free to post just the first few rows of data).