# rake db:migrate hangs on db:schema:dump step

Tags: ruby, rake, jruby, database-migration

When executing `rake db:migrate` command, it hangs on the `Execute db:schema:dump` step.
I am using jruby 1.7.10 and the db gem jdbc-db2 v 9.7. It seems like the `schema.rb` file is successfully created in the db directory but the command still just hangs on that step.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this would be helpful.

Comment: have you checked state of your db? Had same problem with postgresql and db server reloading has solved it

Comment: i had the same issue (rake --trace db:migrate) showed me the hanging step. I found a fix here - just overriding rake task https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453267/how-to-disable-dbschemadump-for-migrations

Answer (score 0):

I just went through something similar where my rake tests kept getting slower. I am using Rails 2.0.2, Ruby 1.8.6, and Oracle 11.2.

The problem was that Oracle has a [recycle bin](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables011.htm#ADMIN01511), and that was filling up as the tables get dropped and recreated every time you run rake tests.

To keep the recycle bin from getting huge, I added a step to purge it after preparing the test database. Create a file `lib/tasks/databases.rake` with the following:

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :test do
    task :prepare do
      # The Oracle recycle bin fills up and slows down the test preparation.
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("purge recyclebin")
    end
  end
end
```

You probably don't want to do this in your production database, but you aren't running db:test:prepare against your production database, are you?

I found the problem by noticing this query running for a long time:

```
 SELECT lower(i.index_name) as index_name, i.uniqueness, lower(c.column_name) as column_name
 FROM user_indexes i, user_ind_columns c
 WHERE i.table_name = 'QCS_USERS'
 AND c.index_name = i.index_name
 AND i.index_name NOT IN (SELECT uc.index_name FROM user_constraints uc WHERE uc.constraint_type = 'P')
 ORDER BY i.index_name, c.column_position
```

Looking at the `user_constraints` table, I saw there were thousands of rows, even after I dropped all my tables, and that led me to [some discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13588946/4794) of the recycle bin.